# Form tells wrong size on Windows 8 — how to get real size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8, windows-xp

Having a WinForms form with form border style set to `Sizable` on Windows 8, the [`DesktopBounds` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.desktopbounds.aspx) tells the correct values:

[image]

In contrast, when having a form border style of `FixedDialog`, the values are wrong:

[image]

On Windows XP, the values are always correct:

[image]

[image]

**My question is:**

How to get the real size of a Window including the complete non-client area?

**Update 1:**

Seems that it is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7). I'll try and see whether this would solve my issue here, too.

**Update 2:**

Just for completeness, here are the results from a VMware Windows 7:

[image]

[image]

**Update 3:**

Finally found a solution which involves using the [`DwmGetWindowAttribute` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) together with the [`DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'll post an answer below.

Comment: If you look closely, Windows XP exhibits the same behavior. It's just that the Windows borders are a single pixel wide rather than the five pixels in Windows 8 (the difference in XP between Fixed and Sizable is 2 whereas it is 10 in Windows 8).

Comment: what gives you the assumption the size is wrong? if you have a look at the Visual Studio designer while you change the `FormBorderStyle` you will actually see it shrink

Comment: @JustinNiessner Yes, I do see that; still the dimensions returned by the Windows XP version actually reflect the real form size, whereas on Windows 8, they do not.

Comment: On Windows 10, if you call `DwmGetWindowAttribute()` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` before the window has first been drawn to the screen (e.g. in order to place a new window correctly on the screen) then you get the same result as `GetWindowRect()` - i.e. including the invisible border. You have to wait until the window has been rendered before it will give the correct result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer my own question, I finally found a solution which involves using the [`DwmGetWindowAttribute` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) together with the [`DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The answer was inspired by [this source code](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/e81176a8398993d3208f9ca83b0422f6e53ef48d/ShareX.HelpersLib/Helpers/CaptureHelpers.cs#L310) which presents a function that seems to work on all system. The core is a function:

```
public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr handle)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
    {
        return GetWindowRect(handle);
    }
    else
    {
        Rectangle rectangle;
        return DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS(handle, out rectangle) 
                   ? rectangle 
                   : GetWindowRect(handle);
    }
}
```

Full code is provided below:

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    // https://code.google.com/p/zscreen/source/browse/trunk/ZScreenLib/Global/GraphicsCore.cs?r=1349

    /// <summary>
    /// Get real window size, no matter whether Win XP, Win Vista, 7 or 8.
    /// </summary>
    public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
        {
            return GetWindowRect(handle);
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rectangle;
            return DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS(handle, out rectangle) ? rectangle : GetWindowRect(handle);
        }
    }

    [DllImport(@"dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out Rect pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

    private enum Dwmwindowattribute
    {
        DwmwaExtendedFrameBounds = 9
    }

    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        // ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Local
        // ReSharper disable FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
        // ReSharper restore FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local
        // ReSharper restore MemberCanBePrivate.Local

        public Rectangle ToRectangle()
        {
            return Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
        }
    }

    private static bool DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS(IntPtr handle, out Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        Rect rect;
        var result = DwmGetWindowAttribute(handle, (int)Dwmwindowattribute.DwmwaExtendedFrameBounds,
            out rect, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rect)));
        rectangle = rect.ToRectangle();
        return result >= 0;
    }

    [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rect lpRect);

    private static Rectangle GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Rect rect;
        GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
        return rect.ToRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using code very similar to this and finding that in a number of situations with high DPI displays the API function just returns 0 and falls back to the GetWindowRect() call instead.

Comment: That source seems to have moved here: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/e81176a8398993d3208f9ca83b0422f6e53ef48d/ShareX.HelpersLib/Helpers/CaptureHelpers.cs#L310

Answer (score -3):

I don't think "wrong" is quite the right way to put it.. you are seeing values you don't understand, but that's not always the same as wrong. The real question is what is the actual problem you are trying to solve by getting the window bounds?

Have you tried the Win32 `GetWindowRect` method? I wonder what that shows.

One hack you could try would be to detect the OS and account for these.

To determine the OS in C#: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283 (that sample doesn't mention Windows 8 specifically, but I assume the SDK has been updated for it)

Comment: Thanks. How would you do that OS switch? I cannot imagine a way to calculate the real values. Even after inspecting `SystemInformation` properties.

Comment: Just tried `GetWindowRect` which return the exact same values.

Comment: Edited with info on how to determine OS.