# How to calculate border thickness of window border in win 7 programmatically

Tags: windows

As you may know that App window looks bigger on win7 than XP.
In win7, we can change the value "Active window Border" and "Border Padding" to change the border thickness of a window.

[image]

For example: By default "Active window Border" is 4 and "Border Padding" is 1.
The window looks like this:

[image]

I change the  "Active window Border" to 10 and "Border Padding" to 10.
the window looks this:

[image]

Now my question is that I need to know the border thickness of window programmatically using C++. How can I do this?
I have researched for sometime, and I have looked at the function GetSystemMetrics.
I tried lots of parameter of this function, but It just make me confused.
Anyone know how to calculate border thickness programmatically?

After some research, it seams that:

```
   border thickness = value of "Active window Border" +  value of "Border Padding".
```

so if you know how to retrieve these 2 values programmatically, it will also help.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you know GetWindowRect has a incompatibility problem with some special window application? check this link for details of the problem.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484894/form-tells-wrong-size-on-windows-8-how-to-get-real-size]. I can replace GetWindowRect with DwmGetWindowAttribute as mentioned in the article. But if I call MoveWindow API using the value returned by DwmGetWindowAttribute, it will make the window become bigger. I need to convert coordinates returned by DwmGetWindowAttribute to the one returned by GetWindowRect, and then pass the converted coordinates to MoveWindow.

Comment: @Luaan This is what I want to solve.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't moving the window work correctly when you use it with `GetWindowRect` instead of the new `DwmGetWindowAttribute`?

Comment: Yes, it works.For the special window, RECT returned by GetWindowRect is smaller than RECT returned by DwmGetWindowAttribute. MoveWindow can only accept the small RECT returned by GetWindowRect. But RECT returned by DwmGetWindowAttribute is the real size of the window.

Comment: MS have provided a API for getting the real size of this kind of special window, but they have not provided a API to update the kind of window, which accept the real size.