# GetWindowRect on Windows 10 is too big

Tags: winapi, windows-10

It worked well in Windows 8.1. But since I updated to Windows 10, GetWindowRect returns rectangle which is too big.

If I make screenshot from window (using ALT+PRINT keys) it gives me correct size of 794x578 Pixels. If I use GetWindowRect it gives me 808x585 pixels.

I have two Monitors with different resolutions. This Problem occurs on both Monitors.

Comment: Got an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or a question? Its hard to know what exactly you're after or which conditions may have a bearing on your output without an minimal example or a question.

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7) or [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484894/form-tells-wrong-size-on-windows-8-how-to-get-real-size) may help.

Comment: @David Heffernan This is not a duplicate and answer you meant is not helpful - it is just a hack which I can't use since I do it in Java.

Comment: It certainly is a duplicate and the fact that you use Java is not relevant. After all, that's not in the question. Even if the question specifically mentioned Java it would still be a duplicate. If you have a follow on question about how to use your new knowledge in you specific context, that would be a new question.

Comment: This Problem was a part of another Problem - getting screenshot of window. The solution was to bitBlt window's Client area.

Comment: GetWindowRect is returning the correct size. Windows 10 has now made the left/right/bottom resizable borders invisible. They are still present, even though ALT+PrnScr doesn't show them. Simply move your mouse past the visible edge of the window, and you will see that the mouse resizes. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139450/getwindowrect-returns-a-size-including-invisible-borders?rq=1