# Dialog has unrequested additional space

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I've designed a Windows Forms dialog that should be reusable in other applications, WPF and Windows Forms. This works fine when I use it in a Windows Forms application, but it causes some layout trouble when called in a WPF application. Dimensions and sizes are inconsistent when measured from the pixels on the screen, from what WinForms API says it is, and from Spy++. The window is 10 pixels wider and taller when run without a debugger than Spy++ says it is, and than I say it should be. What's the problem here? I can't find anything but say it's a badly broken .NET Framework.

Here's the Form class code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DialogTestApp
{
    internal class MyDialog : Form
    {
        public MyDialog()
        {
            Text = "Title";
            Width = 500;   // -> actually 510 (Spy++ says 500)
            Height = 300;   // -> actually 310 (Spy++ says 300)
            Font = SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            TableLayoutPanel mainLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            mainLayout.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 171, 255);   // pink
            mainLayout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            mainLayout.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            mainLayout.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            mainLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));   // Only use minimum required space
            mainLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
            Controls.Add(mainLayout);

            int row = 0;
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Hello world. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque suscipit vestibulum gravida.";
            label.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 12);
            label.MaximumSize = new Size(mainLayout.Width, 0);
            label.AutoSize = true;
            label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            label.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(58, 171, 58);   // green
            label.ForeColor = Color.White;
            mainLayout.Controls.Add(label, 0, row++);

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            textBox.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            textBox.Multiline = true;
            textBox.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
            mainLayout.Controls.Add(textBox, 0, row++);
        }
    }
}
```

Just put this file in an empty WPF application project and call it from the application constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new MyDialog().ShowDialog();
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Here's what it looks with a debugger:

[image]

And without:

[image]

The additional pink border is the 10 pixels that are not supposed to be there. The green label is set to fill up all space.

Comment: Windows 10... No problems.

Comment: Your **internal** `class MyDialog` can not be instantiated in other WPF project (unless it is a friend assembly), maybe you are instantiating another class?

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but `label.AutoSize = true;` and `label.DockStyle = DockStyle.Fill` are conflicts. `AutoSize` will try to pack to the `PreferredSize` when the `Text` or `Font` is changed, where as `DockStyle.Fill` is a hint that could be used by the `LayoutEngine` of the parent control.

Comment: You are not giving authoritative layout instructions.  You tell the TableLayoutPanel to autosize to the control with the RowStyles.Add() call and you tell the label to autosize to its parent with the Dock property.  That makes any size valid.  Throw in Aero appcompat that tries to hide the problem with the fat borders into the mix to make it undiagnosable.  Set at least one size so there is no doubt how big it needs to be.  And wrap the code with SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout so there is only a single layout calculation.

Comment: I need more features: The TableLayoutPanel fills the entire window, it contains more controls below this Label. But the Label must do line-wrapping which it only does in AutoSize mode. But it should also just use so much vertical space as the text needs. Any suggestions how to do that with Windows Forms?

Comment: EDIT: I have updated my question to bring back more of my original layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without the `TableLayoutPanel`, `Label`, and using `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MyDialog())`, the problem still happens. The line that is causing the issue is `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;`

Seems to be the same issue as described here: [Form tells wrong size on Windows 8 — how to get real size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484894/form-tells-wrong-size-on-windows-8-how-to-get-real-size)

**Workaround:**

```
        mainLayout.SizeChanged += delegate {
            label.MaximumSize = new Size(mainLayout.Width, 0);
            //MessageBox.Show("hi"); // called when not ran in debugger
        };
```

Comment: I don't care so much about the actual size of the window. It must be large enough to fit the content. On high DPI systems there will be slight variations anyway. That's what I use the flexible layout container for. But I can't accept that the size values are inconsistent in the client area itself, and that the layouting produces inconsistent values. And I don't understand what the presence of a debugger changes.

Comment: @LonelyPixel So then try removing the line `label.MaximumSize = new Size(mainLayout.Width, 0);` The maximum size is incorrectly calculated (some visual elements issue as pointed out).

Comment: @LonelyPixel See "workaround" in above answer. The simplest solution, which preserves the label text wrapping, is to update the maximum size when the `mainLayout` fires a `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Based on this and the original answer I found another solution: First set `FormBorderStyle`, then set `Width` and `Height`. Then the message box also doesn't appear. There seems to be something in Windows that makes it interpret window sizes differently when executing a WPF application without a debugger. Could be related to Aero that has always shown a strange window screenshot behaviour.