# How can i find the size of a window?

Tags: window, size, overlay

For example if i got this window (which is not part of this project): [image: Example]

Is there a way to get the size of this window? (int x and y)

Thanks,
Revolt

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `HWND` of the window then you can use [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) or [`GetWindowPlacement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518.aspx) to get its position and dimensions.

**Update**: On Vista and later, `GetWindowRect()` can report values that do not take Glass/Aero into account.  To account for that, you can use [`DwmGetWindowAttribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515.aspx) with the `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` attribute instead.

Comment: I tried that but it gives the wrong size, about 1.5x as big as it is supposed to be, on all kinds of windows (google chrome, skype etc.), how can i solve this/any other ways?

Comment: Maybe you are running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7/3192264#3192264. See also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6c1c67a9-5548-4e9b-989f-c7dbac0b1375

Comment: I'm a little confused, what would be the right code then? Because the code in that thread just gives a bunch of errors. EDIT: i tried that DwmGetWindowAttribute but this gives errors aswell, it seems like it does not recognize DWM or the HRESULT in that same part. EDIT2: Just noticed it a second ago: this is a C++ code, got the C# code maybe?