# GetWindowRect detecting bsSingle BoarderStyle

Tags: delphi

For this boarder style i have this using GetWindowRect:

[image]

I wanna always get coordinates for full window. Thanks for help

Comment: GetWindowRect retrieves the *full window*.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz is little cut as you can see.

Comment: @TLama i want this for external windows too

Comment: I don't know what you've done there. Getwindowrect retrieves full bounding rectangle and does not paint it with a red tint.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz i think my code is good cause when i chaange border style to bsSizeable it looks like here http://i.imgur.com/wXkD5Wq.png

Comment: See this: [GetWindowRect on non-resizable windows under Aero Glass](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6c1c67a9-5548-4e9b-989f-c7dbac0b1375/getwindowrect-on-nonresizable-windows-under-aero-glass?forum=windowsuidevelopment). Also look at [`AdjustWindowRectEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Thank You. Using DwmGetWindowAttribute (instead GetWindowRect) fixed my problems http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
uses
  Winapi.DwmApi;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and DwmCompositionEnabled then
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, @R, SizeOf(R))
  else
    Windows.GetWindowRect(Handle, R);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(R.Right - R.Left))
end;
```

Comment: thanks for edit. If i remove (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) then DwmCompositionEnabled should result False on Windows XP, right?