# Get current coordinates of a window (C++)

Tags: c++, window, screen, coordinates

I'm trying to get the x and y coordinates of a specific window relative to the screen (e.g. If the window's position on the screen is (100, 300) then I should retrieve an x-coordinate of 100 and a y-coordinate of 300). How can I achieve this so that I can assign the coordinates to some variables?

```
int x = /*Get x-coordinate*/;
int y = /*Get y-coordinate*/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
int x = rect.left;
int y = rect.top;
```

Comment: GetWindowRect() does not report correct values when Aero glass is enabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/

Answer (score 2):

On Vista and later with Aero glass enabled, you have to use [`DwmGetWindowAttribute(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515.aspx) to account for glass padding.

Otherwise, you can use [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) instead, which does not account for glass padding.