# Dialog shifted to the left and upward in Windows 8

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-8, dialog, position

This dialog shows exactly under button, but in Windows 8 dialog is shifted to the left and upward. How to get the same results in all Windows versions?

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var p: TPoint;
begin
  p := Button3.ClientToScreen(Point(0, Button3.Height));
  MessageDlgPos('', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, p.X, p.Y);
end;
```

[image: Shifted dialog in Win 8]

update:
In case we open Form instead of Dialog, and if that Form has BorderStyle bsSizeable or bsSizeToolWin, then everything is OK. Otherwise (bsDialog, bsSingle, bsToolWindow), Form opens shifted as Dialog from the example above.

Comment: Sounds like a Delphi library bug. Diagnose it by working out whether ClientToScreen is broken, or whether MessageDlgPos is broken. Test the former by inspecting coords. If ClientToScreen works, then MessageDlgPos is broken.

Comment: @David, I think this is not a bug in any of these. Dialog or Form is shifted in the same way in the case of the coordinates (0,0), for example. It seems that the problem is that Windows 8 see point which is located a couple of pixels within the window frame as a starting point. If so, the question is how to make the necessary corrections in a proper way.

Comment: Oh. Well, I guess you need to make it clear in the question. An image would do that.

Comment: Is your app high-DPI aware? If not, Windows has to "fudge" and "lie" to your app when dealing with screen coordinates so the app behaves like it is running in a low-DPI system. That can cause small edge cases when coordinate systems of different resolutions interact/conflict with each other. This affects things like `ClientToScreen()`/`ScreenToClient()`, `(Get|Set)CursorPos()`, etc.

Comment: @Remy, I 'm testing this on a low-DPI system. Also, the difference is not so small - 5px ( SM_CXSIZEFRAME[8px] - SM_CXFIXEDFRAME[3px] )

Comment: VCL is calling `SetWindowPos` with correct coordinates in `TTaskMessageDialog.DoOnDialogCreated` in dialogs.pas. This seems to be an OS issue. Search with something like 'GetWindowRect wrong values' and you'll hit examples like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192232/getwindowrect-too-small-on-windows-7 . Note that the dialogs in middle and rightmost pictures are also off by '1' pixel. I mentioned GetWindowRect because the button's and dialog's window rectangles are reported to have the same 'left' on W7. You can do the same test with W8 and verify if it's an OS problem.

Comment: More than that, Aero makes things like `GetWindowRect()` report "wrong" values to account for DWM affects and bordering so as not to break backwards compatibility with code that does not account for DWM. That is why `DwmGetWindowAttribute(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS)` was added to get the "actual" window rect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the exact code you have shown on Windows 7, I am not able to reproduce the same dialog positioning you have shown in your Windows 7 screnshot.  The `MessageDlgPos` window is offset up and to the left in the same manner as your Windows 8 screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

That being said, I notice you are positioning your `MessageDlg` window relative to the button's *client area*:

[image: screenshot]

If you want the dialog positioned relative to its actual *bottom edge*, you need to call `ClientToScreen()` on the button's `Parent` rather than on the button itself:

```
p := Button3.Parent.ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Left, Button3.Top+Button3.Height));
```

[image: screenshot]

The end result is about the same, though:

[image: screenshot]

Now, why is the overlap occurring in the first place? Because the window is being positioned such that the top-left corner of its non-client area falls at the specified coordinates:

[image: screenshot]

You can adjust the window coordinates to account for that:

```
p := Button3.Parent.ClientToScreen(Point(Button3.Left, Button3.Top + Button3.Height));
Inc(p.X, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFIXEDFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER));
Inc(p.Y, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFIXEDFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER));
```

Which gets you much closer to the desired position:

[image: screenshot]

Note that Aero "tweaks" system metrics a bit, so you might need to use things like [`DwmGetWindowAttribute(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515.aspx) and/or [`GetThemeSysSize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759790.aspx) to get more accurate metrics.

Comment: - *"The end result is about the same, though"* -  A button control does not have a non-client area, that's why. No point in using bounds rect.

Answer (score 1):

After your answers and comments and some additional research, I came to this solution. Tested on Windows 8, 7 with Aero, 7 without Aero and XP. I was hoping for something more simple and stable but ...

```
uses DwmApi;

type
  TNonClientMetricsX = packed record
    cbSize: UINT;
    iBorderWidth: Integer;       iScrollWidth: Integer;
    iScrollHeight: Integer;      iCaptionWidth: Integer;
    iCaptionHeight: Integer;     lfCaptionFont: TLogFontA;
    iSmCaptionWidth: Integer;    iSmCaptionHeight: Integer;
    lfSmCaptionFont: TLogFontA;  iMenuWidth: Integer;
    iMenuHeight: Integer;        lfMenuFont: TLogFontA;
    lfStatusFont: TLogFontA;     lfMessageFont: TLogFontA;
    iPaddedBorderWidth: Integer; // not defined in Delphi 2007
  end;

function GetExtendedFrameOffset(BorderStyle: TFormBorderStyle): integer;
var
  IsEnabled: BOOL;
  NCM: TNonClientMetricsX;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if (DwmIsCompositionEnabled(IsEnabled) = S_OK) and IsEnabled and
     (BorderStyle in [bsdialog, bsSingle, bsToolWindow]) then
  begin
    NCM.cbSize := SizeOf(NCM);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, SizeOf(NCM), @NCM, 0);
    Result := NCM.iBorderWidth + NCM.iPaddedBorderWidth;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var p: TPoint; offset: integer;
begin
  p := Button3.ClientToScreen(Point(0, Button3.Height));
  offset := GetExtendedFrameOffset(bsDialog);
  MessageDlgPos('', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, p.X + offset, p.Y + offset);
end;
```

[image]

update: D2007 includes DwmApi, so no need for complications with LoadLibrary

Comment: I'd let windows place the dialog at the default location.