# How to get actual position of non-resizeable window using GetWindowRect

Tags: c#, winapi

When I call *GetWindowRect()* for a non-resizeable(no **WS_SIZEBOX**) window it does not give me the correct position of window. 
I have tired adding WS_SIZEBOX. But this also didn't work unless I changed the window's size and resized it back.

Is there any way to get the correct position?

Comment: GetWindowRect works fine. You just haven't understood all of the nuances yet. Without a repro, what detail can we offer?

Comment: for GetWindowRect there is difference between the window with WS_SIZEBOX style and without WS_SIZEBOX style. if window does not have WS_SIZEBOX style, GetWindowRect returns small left,top,bottom,right than the one having WS_SIZEBOX style. 

If you dont believe me just check it.

read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027688/5555803) explains.

Comment: The fat windows borders used in Aero were a very significant appcompat problem.  Windows intentionally lies about the window rectangle and pretends that a window still has the skinny 2 pixel borders to ensure that an app does not create a window with a client area that is too small to fit the content.  How this appcompat is related to this question is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetWindowRect** on Windows 7 appears to not include the right and bottom window frame edges (at least with the Aero theme ), if the window was created without the **WS_SIZEBOX**(or another name **WS_THICKFRAME**) style.
The problem is on Aero, windows have the thickframe whether they can be resized or not. But the **GetWindowRect** function thinks that *a non-resizeable window is thinner*. Fortunately, there is another way to get window size and position by using [DwmGetWindowAttribute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969515(VS.85).aspx) (After vista)

```
[DllImport(@"dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out Rect pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

public static bool GetWindowActualRect(IntPtr handle, out Rect rect) 
{
 const int DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 9;
 int result = DwmGetWindowAttribute(handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, out rect, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rect)));

 return result >= 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.code4copy.com/csharp/post/getting-window-rect-using-handle-on-windows-8-and-other